# getting errors trying to send email using msmtp

Tags: msmtp

I'm trying to get email working with msmtp (I used to have fetchmail+procmail for incoming and msmtp for outgoing---trying to restore that), but I'm getting the same errors when sending to different hosts (assuming it's my .msmtprc).

The error message is: "`errormsg='the server sent an empty reply' exitcode=EX_PROTOCOL`"

My .msmtprc (slightly edited)

```
# Set default values

defaults
auth on
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile /home/jim/.msmtp.log

# jim@jdgblogs.com
account jim@jdgblogs.com
host mail.jdgblogs.com
port 465
from jim@jdgblogs.com
user jim@jdgblogs.com
password (is listed here)
```

The details for my email server are copied right out of the details from my hosting company's information for my account, which I have used for this, using msmptp (but that was a long time and another computer running a different Linux.  I verified the file with the certificates, too.

Back in the past, I just did the configuration and it worked.  I'm obviously missing something, but what?  msmtp is supposed to be easy (like sendmail was, when it used sendmail.cf---that I understood; that new system they switched to was impossible to work with).

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for `tls on` is to expect a plain SMTP connection and upgrade it to TLS using the `STARTTLS` command, as you would usually have on port 587 (or sometimes port 25).

Port 465 isn't usually set up that way – the connection instead immediately starts off with a TLS handshake, so you need to specify that using `tls_starttls off`.